# How to Uninstall System Apps by AppCleaner?

Tags: applications, macos

I know there is the graphical method by which you can individually remove each system app such as Chess, Safari, Mail, Game Center, Photo Booth, FaceTime, iBooks, iTunes, Maps, Dictionary, Automator, Notes, Messages, and ImageCapture.

However, this is taking too much time and I would like to control their removal better because my SSDs are only 120 GB and I need more space. 
I am considering the application *[AppCleaner](https://freemacsoft.net/appcleaner/)* enough smart capable of doing the process because it can well decide which is a system app and what is not. 
So the thing what remains is to make the system apps look like normal apps, probably.

A terminal approach would probably be most appropriate if not possible otherwise. 
I would like leave the removal of those applications for *AppCleaner* in the end.

I see these locks on the icons of my systems apps in AppCleaner

[image]

### Space taken by OS X applications

I run patrix's command

```
sudo du -sm /Applications/{Chess,Safari,Mail,FaceTime,iBooks,iTunes,Maps,Dictionary,Automato‌​r,Notes,Messages,ImageCapture}.app
```

I get

```
5   /Applications/Chess.app
40  /Applications/Safari.app
28  /Applications/Mail.app
4   /Applications/FaceTime.app
27  /Applications/iBooks.app
219 /Applications/iTunes.app
8   /Applications/Maps.app
12  /Applications/Dictionary.app
du: /Applications/Automato‌​r.app: No such file or directory
6   /Applications/Notes.app
16  /Applications/Messages.app
```

where you see that I close more than 300 Mb because of them. 
That is too much with my 128 GB SSD.

---

How can you remove system apps by AppCleaner?

Comment: Depends on the app.  I removed iPhotos with it without any problems.

Comment: @user1256923 Did you manage to get rid of those locks inside AppCleaner?

Comment: I have no idea of what locks you are talking about

Comment: Open Terminal, run `sudo du -sm /Applications/{Chess,Safari,Mail,FaceTime,iBooks,iTunes,Maps,Dictionary,Automator,Notes,Messages,ImageCapture}.app` and then consider whether it's really worth the effort of removing them.

Comment: @patrix Yes, I really want to uninstall them. They take more than 300 Mb from my system, which is too much. I also do not need them. Do you have one liner for removing them all.

Comment: We are talking 0.2% of your disk space here. If you think it's really worth it, disable SIP, remove the apps and reenable SIP. But you will get more space back by regularly cleaning out caches, temp folders, old downloads, music not played for months/years etc.

Comment: @patrix What is SIP? How can you disable SIP?

Comment: System Integrity Protection, please use the  search function for details

Comment: just want to throw in a word of warning here if some other Users come here - unless you really know what you are doing don't uninstall/delete System Applications from OS X you may corrupt your entire OS. Some of those Apps like Messages come bundled with Frameworks used by a lot of other Apps e.g. the File Share Function integrated in the Finder and Safari's Site Sharing Function will Fail and cause the whole Safari/Finder to crash if Messages isn't present on your System.

Comment: I've been doing this for years with zero technical issues. No huge space savings, but I'm a minimalist, and removing apps I never use makes my computer feel "clean". You'll need to disable SIP, and I recommend leaving it disabled because apps will sometimes reappear after major updates. Don't do anything stupid like deleting System Preferences or Terminal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The remove the locks so that you can delete macOS system apps go to
AppCleaner -> Preferences -> General Tab
and Uncheck "protect default OSX Apps"

I just cleaned up garageband from macOS Sierra 10.12.5 which was shown as locked (system protected app) as shown in your image.

EDIT: As @leo said, please be warned that removing some system app like messages might break/ crash a whole set of applications or even the entire OS. SO please be careful about trying this

[image]

Comment: Please, add this warning in your answer *just want to throw in a word of warning here if some other Users come here - unless you really know what you are doing don't uninstall/delete System Applications from OS X you may corrupt your entire OS. Some of those Apps like Messages come bundled with Frameworks used by a lot of other Apps e.g. the File Share Function integrated in the Finder and Safari's Site Sharing Function will Fail and cause the whole Safari/Finder to crash if Messages isn't present on your System.*

Comment: Note, it seems to be `/System/Applications`, not `/Applications/` in `v10.15.6`